# "dynamic" keyword and JSON data

Tags: c#, unit-testing, json, asp.net-mvc-2, dynamic

An action method in my ASP.NET MVC2 application returns a JsonResult object and in my unit test I would like to check that the returned JSON object indeed contains the expected values.

I tried this:

```
1. dynamic json = ((JsonResult)myActionResult).Data;
2. Assert.AreEqual(JsonMessagesHelper.ErrorLevel.ERROR.ToString(), json.ErrorLevel);
```

But I get a RuntimeBinderException "'object' does not contain a definition for 'ErrorLevel'".

However, when I place a breakpoint on line 2 and inspect the json dynamic variable (see picture below), it obviously *does* contain the ErrorLevel string and it has the expected value, so if the runtime binder wasn't playing funny the test would pass.

[image: Snapshot of the Locals debugger window]

What am I not getting? What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this? How can I make the assertion pass?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't really need dynamic. Here's an example. Suppose you had the following action which you would like to unit test:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return Json(new { Id = 5, Foo = "bar" });
}
```

and the corresponding test:

```
// act
var actual = subjectUnderTest.Index();

// assert
var data = new RouteValueDictionary(actual.Data);
Assert.AreEqual(5, data["Id"]);
Assert.AreEqual("bar", data["Foo"]);
```

Also you might find the [following blog post](http://trycatchfail.com/blog/post/Simplified-unit-testing-for-ASPNET-MVC-JsonResult.aspx) useful.

Comment: it *is* working. And I appreciate how it works but still looks like quite a hack. Very counter-intuitive to use RouteValueDictionary to query the contents of an anonymous object... I can only hope to remember this solution as I don't think I would have come up with this on my own. Isn't there a different class that would do the same trick with anonymous objects, something not hidden in System.Web.dll? (strange this lives in System.Web.Routing namespace, but NOT in System.Web.Routing.dll)

Answer (score 2):

The `Data` property of the `JsonResult` is of type `Object` this means, although you have a dynamic declaration, the type that is set is still `Object`.  The other issue is that you are using an anonymous type as the `Data` and then trying to access that as a declared instance outside of its applicable scope. Use @Darin's technique for accessing the property values using a `RouteValueDictionary`.